# What is a well-received post?

Tags: support

There is a badge awarded for 5 well-received posts.  How does one define well-received?  Based on views or votes?  How many of each are needed?  The badge also mentions positive question record.  What do you mean?

Comment: This is not to say that this question isn't on topic here (it is), but questions like these have generally already been answered on the mother meta, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), so it generally pays to have a look there before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

> [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

A well received question:

> is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0

Comment: What if it is onhold?

Comment: @XcoderX *on hold* $\ne$ *open*